# Перенаправление на другую страницу php

Tags: php, javascript

есть код отправления почты с формы, нужно сделать перенаправление со страницы отправки на главную страницу сайта.
Вот код отправки:

```
    <?php
   $username = $_POST['name'];
   $email=$_POST['email'];
   $mess = $_POST['mess'];
   $to      = "alexandr.bondarenko.free@gmail.com";
   $headers = 'From: bondsite@alexanderbondarenko.zzz.com.ua' . "\r\n";
   $subject = "Сообщение с блога BS $url";
   $message = "Имя:" .$name ."\nEmail:" .$email ." \n\n\t" .$mess;
   mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Сайт</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/Alexandr_Bondarenko.jpg" type="image/x-icon">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Спасибо за сообщение, я Вам обязательно отвечу!</h1>
    <button><a href="javascript: history.back(-1);">Вернутся
    </a></button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вариант 1

```
<?php
$username = $_POST['name'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$mess = $_POST['mess'];
$to      = "alexandr.bondarenko.free@gmail.com";
$headers = 'From: bondsite@alexanderbondarenko.zzz.com.ua' . "\r\n";
$subject = "Сообщение с блога BS $url";
$message = "Имя:" .$name ."\nEmail:" .$email ." \n\n\t" .$mess;
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

header("Location: /index.php?");
exit();
?>
```

Вариант 2

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1; URL=/index.php">
</head>
```

Вариант 3

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
setTimeout('location.replace("/index.php")',1000); 
</script>
```

Comment: спасибо большое, за развёрнутый ответ!

Answer (score 2):

после отправки e-mail, редирект на `website.ru`

```
$isSend = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
if($isSend){
  header('Location: http://website.ru/');
}
```

Comment: спасибо, работает!